# The "-" key goes up a line in vim

Tags: vim

When I hit the "-" key on my keyboard vim goes up a line. My .vimrc is blank and when I type in `:map -` vim says "no mappings found." I have no idea what could be causing this. I am using a Mac—could it be a Terminal.app problem?

Thanks

Comment: It seems ok for me in *normal* mode. What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I expect the dash key with no configuration to do nothing. Right now, the dash key moves up a line. This happens even if I add `noremap <Up><NOP>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from `:help -`  (it isn't mapped, it is a motion command)

```
-  <minus>      [count] lines upward, on the first non-blank
            character |linewise|.
```

and `+` does the same Downward.

Comment: Thanks. I had no idea. So mapping anything as `-` should change this?

Comment: Yes you should be able to remap it. I don't think I've ever used that key. Lol